# I Lost my ubuntu password with Dual boot mac os

Tags: dual-boot, password, mac

I lost my ubuntu password. And I tried to recover it. Unfortunatelly, I wasn’t able to access the grub. It seems it is working differently With mac os dual boot. I would be very grateful if anyone could help me.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Try to edit your question to contain more information on your problem like your Ubuntu version. Also tell us _how_ exactly did you try to recover your password.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly has a boot loader, even if it's not GRUB. So you could have shared more information about your environment.

Anyway, you can create and access the system via a Live-CD (pen drive), and with `chroot` techniques, access your Ubuntu environment and change the password.